# Ruby Code explained

Tags: ruby

Could somebody please explain this piece of Ruby code:

```
def add_spec_path_to(args) # :nodoc:
  args << {} unless Hash === args.last
  args.last[:spec_path] ||= caller(0)[2]
end
```

I have seen the `<<` operator used for concatenation strings or as a bitwise operator in other languages but could somebody explain it in this context.  Is it somehow appending a blank lamda onto args or am I totally wrong?

I can also see it used like this:

```
before_parts(*args) << block
```

Is the `Hash` a keyword?

I am also unsure of what the `||=` operator is saying.

I am equally in the dark as to what `caller(0)[2]` is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

||= is a common Ruby idiom: it assigns the value only if it is not already set. The effect is the same as code like

```
if some_variable == nil
   some_variable = some_value
end
```

or

```
some_variable= some_value unless some_variable
```

===, when not overridden, compares two objects for identity. In the case of `Hash === args.last`, Hash (which is an object of type Class) is checking to see if it matches the class of the last item in the args Array. The code is making use of the apparent fact that the implementation of Class#=== forces a check on the class of the compared object.

It doesn't work the other way around, for example:

```
a = [{}]
Hash === a.last #=> true
a.last === Hash #=> false
```

The trailing arguments to a method may be supplied as the contents of a hash without needing to provide the {}

So you can do this:

```
def hello(arg1, arg2, arg3)
  puts [arg1.class, arg2.class, arg3.class].join(',')
end

hello 1,2,3 #=> Fixnum,Fixnum,Fixnum
hello :a, "b", :c => 1, :d => 99 #=> Symbol,String,Hash
```

It's often used to provide a variable-length list of optional parameters to the function.

Are you sure you transcribed the original code precisely, btw? In order to get an array of arguments, you would normally add an * to the argument as declared, otherwise args would have to be input as an array, whcih would rather defeat the object.

```
def add_spec_path_to(*args)              # now args is an array
    args << {} unless Hash === args.last # if trailing arguments cannot be
                                         # interpreted as a Hash, add an empty 
                                         # Hash here so that following code will 
                                         # not fail
    args.last[:spec_path] ||= caller(0)[2] # Set the spec_path option if it's not
                                         # already set
end
```

EDIT: Expanding further on the *args thing, try this:

```
def x(*args)
  puts args.join(',')
  puts args.map{|a| a.class }.join(',')
end

x 1,2,:a=>5,:b=>6 
1,2,a5b6
Fixnum,Fixnum,Hash
```

... using *args causes args to be presented to the method as an array. If I don't use the *, like this, for example:

```
def y(args)
  puts args.join(',')
  puts args.map{|a| a.class }.join(',')
end
```

... then args has to be an array before I call the method, or I'll get an "ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments" for anything but one thing passed. So it has to look like this:

```
y [1,2,{:c=>3,:d=>4}]
```

...with the Hash explicitly created with {}. And it's ugly.

All the above tested with MRI 1.8.6, btw.

Comment: No, passing in an Array makes sense, since args is not returned, so otherwise, an appended Hash would be lost.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: you'd call the method like this: some_method([arg1, arg2, arg3], options_hash) ? That's horrid: see the edited answer above...

Answer (score 14):

I'm presuming that `args` is an `Array`.

`Hash` is the name of a class - the first line pushes an empty hash `{}` onto `args` *unless* the last element of `args` is already a `Hash` (the `===` operator for classes tests whether an object is of a certain class).

The `||=` operator is similar to the `+=` operator: it's more or less equivalent to:

```
args.last[:spec_path] = args.last[:spec_path] || caller(0)[2]
```

So, it will set `args.last[:spec_path]` if and only if it is currently unset.

The [`caller`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005955) method returns info about the calling method.

Answer (score 1):

In a little shorter way:

```
def add_spec_path_to(args) # :nodoc:

...

# Append an empty hash to args UNLESS the last arg is a hash.. in which case do nothing
args << {} unless Hash === args.last # so we need a hash. If it is not there, make an empty one and put it there.

...

#if args.last[:spec_path] equals nil or false, set it to caller(0)[2]... 

#so inside that hash from the first part, if :spec_path is not there, create it by using caller(0)[2].

args.last[:spec_path] ||= caller(0)[2] 

...

end
```