# What does the operator ||= stand for in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ||= (or equals) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby)

It's hard to search this in Google because it is a symbol, not text.

What does `||=` stand for?

And how does it work?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It assigns a value if not already assigned. Like this:

```
a = nil
a ||= 1

a = 1
a ||= 2
```

In the first example, a will be set to 1. In the second one, a will still be 1.

Comment: Looks a bit like the SQL `coalesce` operator

Comment: Thanks. . . It just makes sure that the current value of the variable is not overwritten.

Comment: This is nice. Something C# can inspire from. :-)

Comment: Note that both `nil` and `false` are falsey.  So if the values you work with are boolean, it won't distinguish "unassigned" from "assigned to false", later `a ||= true` will override existing `false` value.  (Unlike SQL `coalesce()` ternary logic: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6JMNY7TLVEgTa4GdWg74Sc/0)

Answer (score 10):

From the question [Common Ruby Idioms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613985/common-ruby-idioms):

> is equivalent to

```
 if a == nil || a == false   
    a = b 
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

If b is nil, assign a to it.

```
a = :foo
b ||= a
# b == :foo
```

If b is not nil, don't change it.

```
a = :foo
b = :bar
b ||= a
# b == :bar
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an 'abbreviated assignment' (see Ruby Pocket Reference, page 10)

a = a || b

(meaning a is assigned the value formed by logical or of a, b

becomes

a ||= b

Almost all operators have an abbreviated version (+= *= &&= etc).

Answer (score 0):

i can only guess, but i assume it stands for an logical operator combined with setting a variable (like ^=, +=, *= in other languages)

so `x ||= y` is the same as `x = x || y`

edit: i guessed right, see http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#table_18.4

`x = x || y` means: use x if set, otherwise assign y. it can be used to ensure variables are at least initialised (to 0, to an empty array, etc.)