# equality and null check (Ruby-on-Rails and c#)

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, operators, null-coalescing-operator

I was using the `||=` operator in *Ruby on Rails* and I saw that C# have something similar.

Is `||=` in Ruby on Rails equals to `??` in C# ?

What is the difference if there is one?

Comment: Mind that `||=` **assigns** (if I understood it correctly). Whereas `??` has no side-effect itself: it is like a ternary-operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5691460/67579), the `x ||= y` operator works like:

> This is saying, **set `x`** to `y` if **`x` is `nil`, `false`, or `undefined`**. Otherwise set it to `x`.

(modified, generalized, formatting added)

The [*null-coalescing operator* `??`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) on the other hand is defined like:

> The `??` operator is called the *null-coalescing operator*. It **returns** the left-hand operand if the operand **is not `null`**; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

(formatting added)

Based on that there are two important differences:

1. The **`??` does not assign**, it is like a ternary operator. The outcome *can* be assigned, but other things can be done with it: assign it to *another* variable for instance, or call a method on it; and
2. The **`??` only checks for `null`** (and for instance **not for `false`**), whereas `||=` works with `nil`, `false` and `undefined`.

But I agree they have some "*similar purpose*" although `||` in Ruby is probably more similar with `??`, but it still violates **(2)**.

Also mind that the left part of the null-coalescing operator does not have to be a variable: on could write:

```
Foo() ?? 0
```

So here we call a `Foo` method.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer... yes and no.

The purpose of the `||=` operator in Ruby-on-Rails is to assign the left-hand operand to itself if not null, otherwise set it to the the right-hand operand.

In C#, the null coalescing operator `??` makes the same check that `||=` does, however it's not used to assign. It serves the same purpose as `a != null ? a : b`.