# How to sum elements of an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My problem is two folded. First, I have a table that's not normalized that contains 3 pairs of data (6 columns), which have to be summed. It goes something roughly like this:

```
|-module_a-|-value_a-|-module_b-|-value_b-|-module_c-|-value_c-|
----------------------------------------------------------------
|   02     |    15   |    nil   |   nil   |   nil    |   nil   |
|   01     |    10   |    00    |   10    |   nil    |   nil   |
|   00     |    25   |    nil   |   nil   |   nil    |   nil   |
|   02     |    22   |    01    |   15    |   03     |   20    |
|   03     |    10   |    nil   |   nil   |   nil    |   nil   |
|   02     |     8   |    00    |   5     |   nil    |   nil   |
```

My main goal is to get a total sum of each module, but since they can be mixed in 3 fields, it becomes complicated to do it through activerecord (or so I think).

Anyway, to clean that up, I make an array like this:

```
tok1=Office.select('module_a as module, value_a as value')
tok2=Office.select('module_b as module, value_b as value').where.not(:value_b => nil)
tok3=Office.select('module_c as module, value_c as value').where.not(:value_c => nil)

tok=(tok1+tok2+tok3)
```

Result:

```
|-module-|-value-|
------------------
|   02   |  15   |
|   01   |  10   |
|   00   |  25   |
|   02   |  22   |
|   03   |  10   |
|   02   |   8   |
|   00   |  10   |
|   01   |  15   |
|   03   |  20   |
|   00   |   5   |
```

So far, so good.

Now, I'd like to make a sum of the module values. This would be very simple if I could do a GROUP and SUM via ActiveRecord, but the resulting variable `tok` is an array, so no ActiveRecord functions are possible. If I try to merge them through `tok=tok1.merge(tok2)` I end up with the results of tok2 only, which I assume is cause I'm renaming the fields when I query the Office table, I'm not sure. I tried putting them together in different ways, but I get an error that the relations are not immutable.

Anyway, since the result of doing `tok=tok1+tok2+tok3` ends up with array, I'd like to do the sum by treating it as an array. I've tried using `map`, and after doing a `tok.map{|h| [h.module, h.value]}` I end up with an array like this:

```
{[02, 15], [01, 10], [00,  25}, [02, 22], [03,10], [02, 8], [00,10], [01,15], [03,20], [00, 5]}
```

I don't know how to proceed from here. I tried turning it into a hash, but I'm still too new to the map method so I don't know how to do that exactly. Ideally, I think, it should look like this:

```
{ ["02" => 15],["01" => 10],["00" => 25],["02" => 22],["03" => 10],["02" => 8],
  ["00" => 10],["01" => 15],["03" => 20],["00" => 5]}
```

I've read in other questions how to sum the values with a hash/array like that, so if I were to get it like this I think I'd be set.

Sorry for the messy explanation.

Comment: `module` is a reserved word in Ruby, so be careful about how you use it. You may get unexpected results or errors trying to access an attribute named `module` (such as used in your SELECT clauses above).

Comment: It's just an example. I don't actually have a field with that name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with something like this:

```
arr = [[02, 15], [01, 10], [00,  25], [02, 22], [03,10], [02, 8], [00,10], [01,15], [03,20], [00, 5]]
hash = {}
arr.each do |item|
  hash[item[0]] ||= 0
  hash[item[0]] += item[1]
end
hash # => {2=>45, 1=>25, 0=>40, 3=>30}
```

or without previous map:

```
hash = {}
tok.each do |item|
  hash[item.module] ||= 0
  hash[item.module] += item.value
end
```

Edit: As mentioned in comment by Dima Goltsman (thanks!) it can be rewritten in even shorter form using inject:

```
arr = [[02, 15], [01, 10], [00,  25], [02, 22], [03,10], [02, 8], [00,10], [01,15], [03,20], [00, 5]]    
arr.inject(Hash.new(0)) do |hash, item|
  hash[item[0]] += item[1]
  hash
end # => {2=>45, 1=>25, 0=>40, 3=>30}
```

or

```
tok.inject(Hash.new(0)) do |hash, item|
  hash[item.module] += item.value
  hash
end
```

Comment: Interesting. Could you explain to me what `hash[item[0]] ||= 0` is doing?

Comment: It's actually a shortcut for: ````hash[item[0]] || hash[item[0]] = 0````. Therefore if ````hash[item[0]]```` is already present - nothing will happen. If it's nil (or false) - it will be initialized with value 0. It's one of the most common Ruby idioms - you can find a lot of information about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613985/common-ruby-idioms

Comment: better to use `inject` method, its a shortcut for what you did

Answer (score 2):

Databases are normally really good at grouping and adding things, so I would probably do as much of this in SQL as possible.

```
tok = Office.find_by_sql <<-END_SQL
  SELECT module, SUM(value)
  FROM (
    SELECT module_a AS module, value_a AS value FROM offices
    UNION
    SELECT module_b AS module, value_b AS value FROM offices WHERE value_b IS NOT NULL
    UNION
    SELECT module_c AS module, value_c AS value FROM offices WHERE value_c IS NOT NULL
  ) AS modules(module, value)
  GROUP BY module
END_SQL
```

Evaluates to a collection of `Office` instances with the following attributes:

```
+--------+-------+
| module | value |
+--------+-------+
| 1      | 25    |
| 3      | 30    |
| 0      | 40    |
| 2      | 45    |
+--------+-------+
```

If it were up to me, I would likely create a view with the given SQL query and add an ActiveRecord data model on top of it. That way the `Office` model would not be used for purposes other than originally intended. Since implementing views varies between DBMS's and branches way off from the original topic I will not go into details here.