# Avoiding making multiple calls to Find.find("./") in Ruby

Tags: ruby, block

I am not sure what is the best strategy for this. I have a class, where I can search the filesystem for a certain pattern of files. I want to execute Find.find("./") only once. how would I approach this:

```
  def files_pattern(pattern)
    Find.find("./") do |f| 
      if f.include? pattern
           @fs << f
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit. What do you mean by *execute Find.find("./") only once*?

Comment: I think the asker means to cache the result of `Find.find('./')`.

Comment: @Swanand ah, thanks! I'll have a stab at an answer on that basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remembering the (usually computationally intensive) result of a method call so that you don't need to recalculate it next time the method is called is known as **[memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)** so you will probably want to read more about that.

One way of achieving that it Ruby is to use a little wrapper class that stores the result in an instance variable. e.g.

```
class Finder
  def initialize(pattern)
    @pattern = pattern
  end

  def matches
    @matches ||= find_matches
  end

  private

  def find_matches
    fs = []
    Find.find("./") do |f| 
      if f.include? @pattern
        fs << f
      end
    end
    fs
  end
end
```

And then you can do:

```
irb(main):089:0> f = Finder.new 'xml'
=> #<Finder:0x2cfc568 @pattern="xml">
irb(main):090:0> f.matches
find_matches
=> ["./example.xml"]
irb(main):091:0> f.matches # won't result in call to find_matches
=> ["./example.xml"]
```

---

Note: the `||=` operator performs an assignment only if the variable on the left hand side does evaluates to false. i.e. `@matches ||= find_matches` is shorthand for `@matches = @matches || find_matches` where `find_matches` will only be called the first time due to short circuit evaluation. There are lots of [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609612/ruby-code-explained) explaining it on Stackoverflow.

---

Slight variation: You could change your method to return a list of *all files* and then use methods from `Enumerable` such as `grep` and `select` to perform multiple searches against the same list of files. Of course, this has the downside of keeping the entire list of files in memory. Here is an example though:

```
def find_all
  fs = []
  Find.find("./") do |f| 
    fs << f
  end
  fs
end
```

And then use it like:

```
files = find_all
files.grep /\.xml/
files.select { |f| f.include? '.cpp' }
# etc
```

Comment: that is OK, but if I now want to find first .xml, then .cpp, .c, .h and I do this over a large part of the filesystem, I end up with calling Find.find("./") many times. Or?

Comment: hm.. I think I would need to store all entries of the filessystem in a textfile, and apply the Finder class to the textfile, that should be faster than find() everytime, ofcourse, I must update the textfile before I do the filterting.

Comment: @poseid I have added a variation to the end of the answer. See if that is useful at all.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want to run Find.find to assign the result to an instance variable. You can move what is now the block to a separate method and call that to return only files matching your pattern.

Only problem is that if the directory contains many files, you are holding a big array in memory.

Comment: thanks. i basically missed the point to translate the block back into a method.

Answer (score -2):

how about `system "find / -name #{my_pattern}"`

Comment: use back ticks if you want the results instead of it just going to stdout.

Comment: That would fail in Windows for sure and in any other platform that may not have find available or taking the same parameters. I would do this only as the last measure.

Comment: I actually deleted this answer immediately after posting (but apparently it didn't get deleted) bc there is more problems with it than mentioned after I read the question a second time.