# What does ||= mean?

Tags: ruby

I have a protected method in my application contoller

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
end
```

I was wondering what `||=` means?
I've been trying to search and find out, but to no avail.

Comment: Not sure if the name applies, but in C# is called the null-coalescing operator  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me out and putting me in the right direction!

Comment: Duplicate: [What does `||=` mean in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/995593/), [What does `||=` mean in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3800957/), [what is `||=` in ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3945711/), [Double Pipe Symbols in Ruby Variable Assignment?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4500375/), [What does the “`||=`” operand stand for in ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5124930/), [what does a `||=` mean in Ruby language?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5230162/), [Is the ruby operator `||=` intelligent?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2989862/) and probably many others as well.

Comment: See also [The definitive list of `||=` (OR Equal) threads and pages](http://Ruby-Forum.Com/topic/151660/).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Basically, `a ||= b` means `assign b to a if a is null or undefined or false (i.e. false-ish value in ruby)`, it is similar to `a = b unless a`, except it will always evaluate to the final value of `a` (whereas `a = b unless a` would result in `nil` if `a` was true-ish).

Comment: Also check out *Conditional assignment* on [Ruby Programming/Syntax/Operators](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators#1._Assignment).

Comment: Important to realise it is short circuiting as well - `b` will not be run if `a` is `false-ish` (saving time by not doing an expensive db query, for example).

Comment: it's not `a = b unless a`. Please see http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html for better understanding how it actually works.

Comment: It's not the same as `a = b unless a`. `a ||= b` always returns `a` (after the assignment if applicable), whereas `a = b unless a` returns `nil` if `a` is trueish. This is a very significant distinction, as this mechanism is often used to cache a heavy operation.

Answer (score 5):

||= is a ruby idiom. It means if @current_user is nil (or false) then try to find it by id and assign it to @current_user, otherwise do nothing.

See these [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609612/ruby-code-explained) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613985/common-ruby-idioms).

Answer (score 3):

This is part of Ruby.

If `@current_user` is nil or false, it will be set to `User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])`

Answer (score 1):

Notice the parallels with `a += b`, which is equivalent to `a = a + b`.

So `a ||= b` is equivalent to `a = a || b`.  As others have mentioned, this is the same as `a = b unless a`.

Comment: Actually, Ruby should not assign in case `a` is not `false-ish`, so that `a = a || b` isn't strictly equivalent to `a = b unless a`. One might think specifically of implications in case `a` happens to be a `Hash` for instance.

Comment: No, it isn't, as has been discussed several times already here on SO, dozens of times on the Ruby mailinglists and literally hundreds of times in a myriad of blog posts.

Comment: Oh, right.  Can you give me an an example of when this is not the case?

Comment: It's not the same as `a = b unless a`. `a ||= b` always returns `a` (after the assignment if applicable), whereas `a = b unless a` returns `nil` if `a` is trueish. This is a very significant distinction, as this mechanism is often used to cache a heavy operation.

Answer (score 0):

In ruby 'a ||= b' is called "or - equal" operator. It is a short way of saying if a has a boolean value of true(if it is neither false or nil) it has the value of a. If not it has the value of b.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, a ||= b means assign b to a if a is null or undefined or
>   false (i.e. false-ish value in ruby), it is a shortcut to a = b unless
>   a.
>
> share|edit answered Sep 26 '11 at 14:48
>
> Romain 6,9711330

In addition to this answer here`s an example -

```
arr = nil || []
arr0 ||= []

arr <=> arr0    *#=> 0*
```

This means `arr` expression and `arr0` expression are equal.

Hope this helps to understand better `||=` operator.