# What does ||= mean?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ||= (or equals) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby)
>   [What does ||= mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556902/what-does-mean)

I have just started learning RubyMotion and in a lot of examples I see the `||=` syntax.  What does this mean?

Here is an example:

```
def window
  @window ||= begin
    w = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds
    w.rootViewController = @navigationController
    w
end
```

It is difficult to search symbols, google ignored the symbols in my query.

Comment: Duplicate: [What does `||=` mean in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/995593/), [What does `||=` mean in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3800957/), [what is `||=` in ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3945711/), [Double Pipe Symbols in Ruby Variable Assignment?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4500375/), [What does the “`||=`” operand stand for in ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5124930/), [what does a `||=` mean in Ruby language?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5230162/), [Is the ruby operator `||=` intelligent?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2989862/), …

Comment: … [What does `||=` mean?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/7556902/), [What does “`||=`” do in Ruby 1.9.2?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/7714803/) ['`||=`' operator in Ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/8506257/), [What does the '`||=`' operator do in ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/9698946/), [How does “`||=`” work?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/11123385/), and probably many others as well. See also [The definitive list of `||=` (OR Equal) threads and pages](http://Ruby-Forum.Com/topic/151660/).

Comment: Use symbolhound.com to search for symbols.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Why do you list all the duplicates?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is an assignment operator which means: or assign this value to a variable.

So if you did something like `x ||= y`this means`x || x = y` so if x is nil or false set x to be the value of y.

Comment: I was looking at the link @Marc B posted above under "Conditional assignment."

Comment: well its essentially the same thing. If you are doing x = x || y, if as long as the left operand return false the right operand will be evaluated. In the case you use x ||= y, if x is false x gets y and x = x|| y, if x != x (false) x gets y.

Comment: Were you aware that this was a duplicate question when you answered it?

Comment: No, I did not know it was a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

This Operator only sets the variable if the variable is false or Nil.